# Saving session in php file and accessing them

Tags: php, html

Is it possible in the world of PHP?
I want to store session in PHP file on my server , like user's email **$_SESSION['email']**  for 20mins  or saved forever unless deleted manually when its posted. Within the 20mins , if the user submit same email again . They get redirected to thank you page. "Your email has been received" Something like that.

Comment: It's possible to store data in a file, yes.  Or, more commonly, in a database.  It's not really clear what you're asking, or what you've tried and what didn't work in that attempt.

Comment: but i was asking if that was possible because i dont know where to start from. But i already coded my page .   Clearly my questions , how do i save the session variables in another php file and re-accessed them again

Comment: Generally one wouldn't save data *to a PHP file*.  If you must save data to a file (instead of a database) then you'll at least want to use some kind of structured data format.  JSON is commonly used.  You can also make up your own format if you prefer.  In that case you're really just reading/writing a text file.  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  There are many tutorials and examples available to help you write to a file in PHP.

Comment: yes i'm able to do that , save session in file , but how do i accessed them again. i want to prevent user from submitting their email twice on my page , just once, if they do, they get redirected to thank you page.

Comment: *"but how do i accessed them again"* - If you've already written to a file, then your next step is to **read from** a file.  There are many examples and tutorials available online to help you read a file in PHP.  You are encouraged to at least **try**.

Comment: Aww ok, sir you've motivated me sir, i will but please dont leave here.